# How to position divs with jQuery or JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Is there anyone who can help me position the DIV on the bottom of the screen using JavaScript or Jquery? am creating a chart so i need to place the textarea inside this DIV.

e.g

```
<html>
 <head>
  <style type="text/css">
   #txtMsg{
    width:780px;
    height:150px;
    margin:0 auto;
   }
  </style>
</head>

 <div id='txtMsg'> 
  textarea here
 </div> 
</html>
```

The aim is to display the text-area on each screen at the bottom and at the same position when browser re-sized

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Vanilla css solution , no need in javascript/jquery:

```
#txtMsg{
 width:780px;
 height:150px;
 position: fixed;
 bottom:0;
 right:0;
}
```

JSFiddle , please: http://jsfiddle.net/HDQux/1/

Comment: Note that old IE as well as most mobile browsers have trouble positioning fixed elements correctly. For example, Opera Mobile only repositions them (w.r.t. the page) on touch end, and it repositions them incorrectly (~50px downwards) if you scroll down.

Comment: @codefun great , but note about limitations mentioned by Jan DvoraK